# I want help to write a batch file to copy the content of text files in a folder with its file name on the top

Tags: batch-file

Say I have a file name a.txt, b.txt, c.txt ...... the batch file should generate a result in a file.txt as:

a.txt
content of the file
b.txt
content of the file
c.txt
content of the file
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Amusing your text files are in the same folder as your batch files you could use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo merging the files
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type a.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!>>file.txt
)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type b.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!>>file.txt
)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type c.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!>>file.txt
)
echo Done the file is saved in %CD%
pause
```

I havent tested it yet but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal

    set "outputFile=file.txt"

    (for %%f in (*.txt) do if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%outputFile%" (
        echo %%~nxf
        type "%%~ff"
    )) > "%outputFile%"

    endlocal
```

For each txt file, if it is not the file we are generating, echo its name and its content. All the data echoed/typed is send to output file.

Comment: thanks @MC ND this was the answer I was looking for.